# How to write a new file when new post has been published in Wordpress

Tags: plugins, posts, publish

I having a problam with my wordpress plugin. The plugin does whenever new post has been published, it will automaticly create a new file with that post content.

this is my code

```
function example($post_ID) {
    global $post;
    $content = htmlentities(get_post_field('post_content', $_GET['post']));
    file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . '\myFile.txt', $content);
}
add_action('publish_post', 'example');
```

But when i change the code some think like this. this will working

```
file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . '\myFile.txt', "Some string here");
```

Comment: If you want a question migrated, ask the moderators. I flagged your first question on SO – http://stackoverflow.com/q/10338875/299509 – for migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you pass post id ?

```
 $content = htmlentities(get_post_field('post_content', $post_ID));
```

Comment: Oh my god.... WOW... finaly it works... thanks a lot man.. u saved my time. :)